# Replace a div tag with table

Tags: html, css, division, tabular

I need to replace a div tag with a table tag. I  Choose table tag cause it easier for me personally  to do the edits and updating of a website
This is the div code with its CSS. How to replace it to Table tag instead of div tag on this given code:

Code:

```
<div class="cont-grid">
    <div class="cont-grid-info">
    <h3>Tittle</h3>

         <p>Hellow World<br/>
          <h3><b>FName, 
           LastName
           ,FathersName</b>
            </h3>
         </p>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS styles

```
.cont-grid-info{
    float:right;
    width: 69.5%;

    .cont-grid-info h3{
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;

}
.cont-grid{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
```

Comment: @Wowsk placed it inside my css?

Comment: Yes, the css for your div you want to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="cont-grid">
    <table class="cont-grid-info">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Tittle
            </th>
            <th>
                Tittle
            </th>
            <th>
                Tittle
            </th>
            <th>
                Tittle
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Hellow World
            </td>
            <td>
                FName
            </td>
            <td>
                LastName
            </td>
            <td>
                FathersName
            </td>
            <tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If this you will like to do:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>FName</th>
    <th>LastName</th>
    <th>FathersName</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>the input name</th>
    <th>the input lastaname</th>
    <th>the input fathersname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    .. so on on the other imputs
  </tr>
</table>
```